# ¿tipo de archivo en HTML?

Tags: html

Cual sería la **diferencia** entre usar:

```
<script></script>
```

Con el `type` de esta forma:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

O esta forma:

```
type="application/javascript"
```

Comment: Por esto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type text/javascript está obsoleto, no se debe usar. Usa siempre application/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las diferencias no son muchas, casi nada, bueno **nada**.

`<script></script>` Permite la inserción de codigo al lado del cliente como **Javascript** esta etiqueta sin atributos, básicamente no estarías especificando  el MIME del script y en caso de no especificarse es `text/javascript` esto apartir de **html5**.

**Con:**

`type="text/javascript"` Simplemente especificas que el lenguaje a utilizar sera Javascript

**Y con:**

`type="application/javascript"` Igual que **text/javascript**, aunque es preferible utilizar el anterior.

ademas de esas dos opción también tienes

`type="text/ecmascript"` Que especifica el lenguaje de programación publicada por ECMA International basado en javascript.

y

`type="text/vbscript"` Que especifica el lenguaje de programación interpretado basado en Visual Basic.

Comment: Es importante destacar que `<script></script>` dará el valor `text/javascript`  cuando no es especificado solo a partir de HTML5; y `application/javascript` no está soportando en navegadores <= IE8.

Answer (score 0):

No habría diferencia, "text/ javascript" ya está obvsoleto aunque es admitido en HTML 4 y 5, a diferencia de la aplicación / javascript, tiene soporte para varios navegadores.